# AJAX скролит элемент наверх

Tags: jquery, ajax

Привет, на протяжении долгого времени долблюсь с AJAX. Есть что-то на подобие чата. Проблема заключается в том, что сообщения из БД выводятся посредством AJAX каждые 10 секунд. Эти сообщения выводятся в блок .content Когда происходит очередной AJAX запрос этот блок .content скролится наверх. Как убрать этот скролл?

```
function show()
{
    $.ajax({
        url: "includes/vivod.php", // Путь к php скрипту который будет загружать заголовки
        cache: false,
        success: function(html){
            $(".content").html(html); // Блок куда будем выводить информацию
        }
    });
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    show();
    setInterval(show, 10000); // Интервал обновления в миллисекундах      
});
```

Comment: [event.preventDefault()](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) Вам поможет

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду сообщения чата скролятся вверх? Т.е. у вас полностью обновляется контент чата и у него скрол вверху, верно?

Comment: предполагаю, что в момент  $(".content").html(html) и происходит скролл, а точнее не скролл. Представьте, что вы удалили контент из $(".content"). Ваша страница стала по высоте меньше и экран сместился вверх, т.к. контента нет. Затем вы добавили контент в $(".content") - данные добавились, а страница вниз не перешла

Comment: Dan the Hat, куда именно это ставить? Голову сломал уже.

Comment: Oleg Reym, точно

Comment: Skywave, нет, там все подогнано по vh xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function scrollToBottomChat() {
  $('.content')[0].scrollTop = $('.content')[0].scrollHeight;
}

function show() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "includes/vivod.php", // Путь к php скрипту который будет загружать заголовки
    cache: false,
    success: function(html){
      $(".content").html(html); // Блок куда будем выводить информацию
      scrollToBottomChat(); // После обновления скроллим
    }
  });
}
$(document).ready(function(){
  show();
  setInterval(show, 10000); // Интервал обновления в миллисекундах      
});
```

У вас не происходит скролл наверх, у вас просто полностью обновляется содержимое .content и он имеет по дефолту нулевой скролл.

Comment: Все равно поднимается наверх и вниз не опускается. Могу ссылку дать и аккаунт, чтобы не регистрироваться, посмотрите.

Comment: Давайте попробуем. reymoleg@gmail.com

Comment: Попробуйте вот эту строчку $('.content')[0].scrollTop = $('.content')[0].scrollHeight; поменять на эту:  
$('.content .wrapper')[0].scrollTop = $('.content .wrapper')[0].scrollHeight; У вас там вложенность по элементам, и нужно скроллить .wrapper. Так же вызовите эту функцию при загрузке страницы scrollToBottomChat()